# Is there a gesture to drag and drop with Expose on Lion?

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch, expose

I know it could be done by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> button while dragging an item but I really need the five-finger-gesture for that.

On Snow Leopard, I could drag an item with my thumb and then use the remaining four fingers to expose all the apps/windows to drop this item in any app/window in the current space or any other space.

Is there an equivalent in Lion?

Comment: There is no five-finger gesture, and using the available gestures still works. Please explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when this has been re-enabled, but in **OS X Lion 10.7.4** I am able to do the following:

1. Click drag and object in Window A and hold it with your thumb.
2. Initiate App Exposé/Mission Control using a four finger gesture. Do not release your thumb.
3. Drag the object to Window B using one of the remaining four fingers.

So, this is basically the same as you used to do.

Comment: Thnx a lot but unfortunately I can't find this gesture type on the list of touchpad gestures.

Please help.